# How to display number in percentage

Tags: php, math, percentage

I wanted to know how I present a percentage, here is the code

```
//The number taken from the database
$minos = $ud['bnk']['gold'];

The number that is supposed to be in percent through the database (the database has a number and not a percentage for example 2)
$plus=  $ud['bnk']['ent_level'];

And here is a simple calculation of X + 2% = Y
$sava = $minos + $plus;
```

I tried to do this, according to an internet guide, but it doesn't work for me, I want the number to be a percentage and not successful

```
function get_percentage($total, $number)
{
  if ( $total > 0 ) {
   return round($number / ($total / 100),$ud['bnk']['ent_level']);
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

$minos = $ud['bnk']['gold'];
$plus =  get_percentage(100,$ud['bnk']['ent_level']).'%';
$sava = $minos + $plus;
```

Comment: `$percent = $number ÷ $total * 100;`

Comment: Hello Daan, I didn't understand where to put it, I tried to play with what you gave me, and it's not clear to me.

Comment: You would put it in the same place as your existing percentage calculation formular, to replace it. To understand why, look closely at what Daan wrote, compared you yours. In particular, look closely at what symbol is in between `$total` and `100`, compared to yours. Honestly though, you can look up the formula for calculating a percentage in thousands of places online. This is basic maths. The problem is not with your PHP code as such, you just used the wrong maths.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the equation with what you gave me, thank you very much, the way is:

```
$minos = $ud['bnk']['gold'];
$plus =  ($minos / 100) * $ud['bnk']['ent_level'];
$sava = $plus;
```

Thanks so much to everyone who helped